# SAML support for jersey rest application

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, saml-2.0, service-provider

I have a java jersey rest application. This application will be service provider and keycloak will be used as identity provider. The protocol used will be SAML.
Every example that I find on the internet is using spring security SAML. Is there any other way we can add SAML filter in jersey application? Isn't there any jersey library for this?

Thanks in advance!